# How to get the taxes from the tax I created on my token?

Tags: solana-program, solana-wallet-adapter

After I have already created my token and defined 5.5% of tax in it and also defined a wallet that will receive it what next?  If I upload it to dex, I will already receive the commissions and can actually use them?

Comment: Same issue, but not solving. I don't see any claimable fee on dexlab. I can't make any claim on phantom, when I click on the token. On Solflare I can't even add my token, due it's 2 weeks old.

Answer (score 0):

You can withdraw the withheld tokens from accounts using the `withdraw-withheld-tokens` command on the SPL Token CLI, ie:

```
spl-token withdraw-withheld-tokens \
 <TOKEN_ACCOUNT_ADDRESS_TO_WITHDRAW_FROM> \
 <DESTINATION_TOKEN_ACCOUNT>
```

More info at
https://spl.solana.com/token-2022/extensions#example-withdraw-withheld-tokens-from-accounts